# How to get media from clients Instagram and Facebook public page on the server side?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

I know it's probably a common question but i couldn't find a solution for my specific case. We have created a Facebook App on our Business Facebook account and the client has given us page moderator permission on his page. Using this we have been able to generate a Never expiring page token and download the posts from the clients page. We would like to do the same for the clients Instagram posts.

After reading the GraphAPI docs i have concluded that we need "instagram_basic" permissions from the client but when i choose page in the Graph API Explorer and try adding "instagram_basic" permission the whole API Explorer disappears.

We do not have the Instagram Business account but the client has. His posts are all public and we need only his posts. I'm confused by the docs what tokens can we use. Page token seemed appropriate for Facebook but not for Instagram. This is all downloaded server side and mashed together with the clients other blog posts and similar feeds. There is no App involved so no Facebook, IG login.

Comment: is the instagram account connected to the facebook page? "no app involved" is weird, you have to create an app in order to get a page token... anyway, with a page token you can get the connected instagram account with its id. with id/media and the page token, you can get the media of the account.

Comment: Thank you I will check with the client if his page is connected to the Instagram account. To clarify I meant there is no client app where i can ask for permission there is only a server side app and when i added the Instagram product in the app and selected "instagram_basic" permission the app review process popuped up requiring a screencast of the application and there is nothing to show. The client will give us the necessary permission but i do not know what he needs to do. I also do not see a reason for the app to go through a review process for wanting do download own IG and FB posts.

Comment: review is not neccessary in that case, and having a role in the page should be good enough.